# Proof that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{I}_{ \Gamma_i}$ is a Poisson Random Measure on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: probability-theory

For $X_i \sim \text{i.i.d}~ \text{expo(1)}$ defined on $E=[0,\infty)$, and $\Gamma_i = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. I want to show that $N=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{I}_ {\Gamma_i} $ is a homogenous Poisson random measure (PRM).

For $k \ge 1$ and $A \in$Borel$(E)$, I want to solve:

$$
P(N(A)=k) =  P\left ( \sum_{i=k}^\infty \mathbb{I} \left ( \Gamma_i \in A \right )=k \right)
$$
where $\mathbb I$ is an indicator function.Im having trouble simplifying the inner probability involving the $\Gamma_i$ due to their dependence.

**Update**: Focusing on the distribution of $N_t = N([0,t])$, given by:
\begin{align*}
P(N([0,t]=k) &= P(X_1+X_2+...+X_{k+1}>t,X_1+X_2+...+X_{k}<t)\\
&=\int_{y=0}^t \frac{y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-y} \int_{x=t-y}^\infty e^{-x}
\, \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{y=0}^t \frac{y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-y} e^{-(t-y)}\, \mathrm dy\\
&= e^{-t}\int_{y=0}^t \frac{y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\, \mathrm dy\\
&=e^{-t}\frac{t^k}{k!}
\end{align*}
So $N_t \sim \text{Poi}(t-0 = t)$. Would this be enough to say that if we now look at any $[a,b]\in$Borel$(E)$, then we would have $N_{[a,b]} \sim \text{Poi}({b-a})$?

Comment: $\Gamma_i=X_i$? Then where is the dependence?

Comment: @Did forgot to add the definition of $\Gamma$, edited now.

Comment: Ah... Then for $j=\infty$ this is simply a Poisson process but I guess there is no general simple formula for $j$ finite.

Comment: @Did actually I am trying to prove that $N= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{I}_{\Gamma_i} $ is a homogenous poisson process on $E$. This was an intermediate step in my working

Comment: OK. The result you are really interested in ($j$ infinite) is simple, the question you asked here ($j$ finite) is unsolvable.

Comment: @Did I updated to put the whole attempt, I thought it would cut down if I just asked about that specific aspect of the attempt

Comment: @Did you mentioned for j infinite there is a solution, I'm wondering if there is a reparameterisation to remove dependence or I'm over thinking it? I was looking into the Renyi Representation as a possible way of tackling this

Comment: The usual approach is to first compute the distribution of every $N_t:=N([0,t])$. Could you do that?

Comment: @Did I'm not quite sure how to do that, where does the $t$ come into it?

Comment: @Did is not easier to find the laplace functional of N and show it has the same form of the LF of a poisson random measure?

Comment: You realize the results you suggest to prove are vastly more powerful than (and include as a special case) the one I try to direct you to? To think this would be "easier" is not the most plausible conception one can have.

Comment: @Did Do you then mean: $P ( N( [0,t] =0) = P( X_1>t ), P ( N( [0,t] =1) =P( X_1<t, X_1+X_2 > t ) $ and so on? If so, how do we generalize for any borel($A$)

Comment: Once again: the suggestion is to first deal with $[0,t]$.

Comment: @Did I think I understand what you were hinting at, I've updated my attempt

Comment: @Did Is there a way to translate the result from $N_t$ to the general result for any interval in the sigma algebra? I'm not really sure how to do it from first principles, it's a lot tricker than the case when $a=0$

Comment: I do not see how you computed the distribution of $N_t$. Once this step is solidified, one should be able to deal with increments on disjoint intervals--and there independence will have to be proven somehow.

Comment: @Did you mean the working? The working has been added now